# Events are not being tracked

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up event tracking on a phone number link using the following code,

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call', 'click', 'Header phone link', { nonInteraction: true });" href="tel:+123456789">+123456789</a>
```

Its been over 24 hours and I did not see any events being tracked so I added the Google Analytics Debugger on Chrome and on inspection I found the following error,

```
Running command: ga("send", "event", "Phone Call", "click", "Header phone link", {nonInteraction: true})
Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

I've tried moving the analytics code to the header from the footer on a suggestion I found somewhere but it hasn't helped.

What else can I do?

EDIT: I'm using gtag.js

Comment: I guess `onclick` should be after `href`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');` command on your head section before you can send any event.

For this, it is beneficial to include ***create*** just after you have included Google analytics code on your site. It must look something like this

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
```

---

On a side note,

- I would recommend you to use Google tag manager, as then it will be very easy for you to manage tags.
- Right now `gtag` object is used in GA. I would recommend you to go tou your property and have a look into tracking info.

---

### UPDATE

Since you edited that you are using GTAG, then assuming you have implemented the main tracking code correctly, use this to send an event

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'non_interaction': true
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. Could you point me in the direction of some documentation of the entire process especially `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');`. I haven't got any other code between the main tracking and the onclick code.

Comment: @Tushar that worked, thanks! Is the `'non_interaction': true` required? Isn't it true by default?

Comment: It is not true by default. since you have mentioned in your OP, I have included it in my answer.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks!